# How to avoid table appearing during scrolling (where it is not required) when using heading with position: 'sticky'

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My question is related to having a header in my table that has the style - position: 'sticky'. And that's where all the problems come from. Now more

I set a sticky header to make it easy for the user to scroll through long tables. But the header in the table has rounded edges (top right and top left), and the table itself has a box-shadow. And it turns out that when the user scrolls the table, the box-shadow scrolls along with the table, and space is visible in the gap between the header and the beginning of the table.

Perhaps the description is confusing, here is a video (note the box-shadow and rounded edges of the table)

My header very simple

Header.jsx

```
 import { styles } from "../DataTablesStyles";

 export default function Header() {
    return (
        <TableHead sx={{position: 'sticky',top: '0px',zIndex: '1'}}>
            <TableRow >
                <TableCell style={styles.TableHeaderStyleFirst}>Actions</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={styles.TableHeaderStyle}>Status</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={styles.TableHeaderStyle}>Device ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={styles.TableHeaderStyle}>Model</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={styles.TableHeaderStyle}>Operation<br></br>System</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={styles.TableHeaderStyle}>Api<br></br>level</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={styles.TableHeaderStyle}>Last activity</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={styles.TableHeaderStyleLast}></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    );
}
```

DataTablesStyles.js

```
// In TableStyle I define the style of the whole table
const TableStyle = {
    borderTopRightRadius: '8px',
    borderTopLeftRadius: '8px',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: '16px',
    minWidth: '750px',
    boxShadow: '0px 0px 10px 0.1px rgba(124, 159, 236, 0.3)',
}

const TableHeaderStyle = {
    fontWeight: '400',
    fontSize: '14px',
    letterSpacing: '0.4px',
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: '#EAECF4',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: '2px',
}

const TableHeaderStyleFirst = {
    borderTopLeftRadius: '8px',
    fontWeight: '400',
    fontSize: '14px',
    letterSpacing: '0.4px',
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: '#EAECF4',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: '2px',

}

const TableHeaderStyleLast = {
    borderTopRightRadius: '8px',
    fontWeight: '400',
    fontSize: '14px',
    letterSpacing: '0.4px',
    color: 'black',
    backgroundColor: '#EAECF4',
    borderTopRightRadius: '8px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: '2px',
}
```

I think you already understand the essence of my question. How to make it so that the shadow does not scroll and the gap is not visible

Comment: _"and the gap is not visible"_ - by either eliminating the gap, or limiting scrolling to the container to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes to get this right. Firstly, I think you really want the scrollbar to be on the table body, and not the bit with the header as well. This makes more sense because only the content then has a scrollbar. It also has the affect the header is no longer overlaid (but it still sticks to the top) since the header is no longer part of the scroll content.

[image: overlaid header]

I had to add a few more class names here and there to support this change. It's admittedly very fiddly - tables are on of the more ancient parts of the HTML spec and you have to apply various tricks with tricking the rows/header etc to lay out properly with `display: table` in a few places -- since to put the scroll on the `tbody` you have to make that `display: block` and that would otherwise mess up the table/cell layout.

Anyway, here it is. You will now control the height in the `.TableBodyStyle` which I've set to `400px` for demonstration purposes.

Also here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-brook-i88vim

DevicesTable:

```
import { Table, TableBody, TableContainer } from "@mui/material";
import DevicesTableHeader from "./DevicesTableHeader";
import DevicesTableCell from "./DevicesTableCell";

export default function DevicesTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer className="TableContainerGridStyle">
      <Table className="TableStyle">
        <DevicesTableHeader />
        <TableBody className="TableBodyStyle">
          <DevicesTableCell />
          <DevicesTableCell />
          <DevicesTableCell />
          <DevicesTableCell />
          <DevicesTableCell />
          <DevicesTableCell />
          <DevicesTableCell />
          <DevicesTableCell />
          <DevicesTableCell />
          <DevicesTableCell />
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

DevicesTableCell:

```
import React from "react";
import { TableCell, TableRow } from "@mui/material";
import "./DataTablesStyles.css";

export default function DevicesTableCell() {
  return (
    <TableRow className="TableCellStyle">
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Some Text</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
}
```

DevicesTableHeader:

```
import "./DataTablesStyles.css";
import { TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from "@mui/material";

export default function DevicesTableHeader() {
  return (
    <TableHead
      sx={{
        display: "table",
        tableLayout: "fixed",
        width: "100%"
      }}
    >
      <TableRow className="TableRowStyle">
        <TableCell className="TableHeaderStyle">Actions</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="TableHeaderStyle">Status</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="TableHeaderStyle">Device ID</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="TableHeaderStyle">Model</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="TableHeaderStyle">
          Operation<br></br>System
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell className="TableHeaderStyle">
          Api<br></br>level
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell className="TableHeaderStyle">Last activity</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="TableHeaderStyle"></TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}
```

The CSS:

```
.TableContainerGridStyle {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.TableStyle {
  display: block;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  min-width: 750px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0.1px rgba(124, 159, 236, 0.3);
}

.TableHeaderStyle {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #eaecf4;
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.TableHeaderStyle:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.TableHeaderStyle:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  padding: 2px 25px 2px 22px;
}

.TableCellStyle {
  border-top: 2px solid #eaecf4;
  border-bottom: 1.1px solid #eaecf4;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

tr.TableCellStyle {
  display: table;
}

.TableCellStyle td:last-child {
  padding-right: 22px;
}

.TableBodyStyle {
  display: block !important;
  overflow: overlay;
  table-layout: fixed;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.TableBodyStyle tr:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
}

.TableBodyStyle tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: height should i also put in TableStyle? I added box-sizing and height but the problem persists

Comment: Your codesanbox isn't precisely the same as the code you posted, would you mind editing to reproduce the exact issue and I will try my best to help :).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-glade-iveoo4  I have edited the code as you requested. Now there is a header, a body and a component that collects them and forms a table. My problem is also visible there: when the page scrolls down, the header loses the box-shadow on top and on the rounded edges

Comment: @Paul Ive edited my answer with a complete solution :)

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. True, I still have to work hard to connect this code with all the other elements of the site :) Tell me, is it possible to do so that max-height: 400px; was not fixed, but adapted to the page size?

Comment: Yeh its possible. You could just use `height: 100%` so it fills the container, but you have to make sure all the ancestors up then tree are also height 100%. Or you could look into CSS flexbox.

Comment: Maybe you can help me out again. How to make it so that when the table overflows horizontally, a horizontal scroll appears in the table itself, and not on the page. Is it possible?